# SSIS Package is executing successfully, While job with same package is failing

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, package, jobs

I have created a SSIS package for tickting system. It loads the data from Excel to Staging table then to production table.
The steps of the package are as follows:
1. Truncate Staging table.
2. Load excel to staging table.
3. Call a procedure that is responsible for data transformation as well data loading from staging to prod table.

I have imported the package on SQL Server integration services.
The package is executing succesfully. But when i ran the job with the package I got the following error.

```
Source: TicketWeeklyLoad Connection manager "Ticket Weekly Sheet Connection Manager"     
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft JET Database Engine"  
Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file 'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\DATA\SSIS\File.xls'.  
It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.".  
End Error  Error: 2015-04-06 16:46:53.40     Code: 0xC020801C     
Source: Load Weekly Excel to Tct_Stg Ticket Weekly Source Excel Sheet [103]     
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  
The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Ticket Weekly Sheet Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  
There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  
End Error  Error: 2015-04-06 16:46:53.40     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Load Weekly Excel to Ticket_Stg SSIS.Pipeline    
 Description: Ticket Weekly Source Excel Sheet failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  
End Error  Error: 2015-04-06 16:46:53.40     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Load Weekly Excel to Ticket_Stg SSIS.Pipeline    
 Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2015-04-06 16:46:53.40     
Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Load Weekly Excel to Ticket_Stg     
 Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  
Started:  4:46:53 PM  Finished: 4:46:53 PM  Elapsed:  0.313 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.
```

In Addition **Run64BitRuntime** set to **false** and the package is also using *32 bit runtime* that i have set using Executing Optins tab in the Package properties.
File is closed and i do have the permission to open it.
I am using windows 8, SQL server 2014 and Visual Stdio 2010 for SSIS.
Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: Is the SQL Server running on your computer or a different computer? What is the SQL Agent service account? _You_ might have permission to open it but the SQL Server Agent Service account might _not_.

Comment: I am connecting to the local server using Windows Authentication.

Comment: The most likely issue is that the Account under which SQL Server Agent Job is running does not have permissions to access the file.

Comment: I have a single account that i am using to login to my system, as well as to connect to the SQL Server. Please let me know if i am making some mistake.

Comment: use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186264.aspx) to identify which account your agent job is running under

Comment: Got it. Job ran successfully. I have selected 'Local System' as Built-In account. Previously it was 'Network Service' and the excel file was in my local system. That was the cause of the error.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Job was failing because the *Network Service* was set as *Built-In* account in SQL Server Agent. 
But the Excel file was on my local system.
 Once I selected *Local System* as *Built-in* account job ran successfully.